# Weight dependent routing in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, routing, network-analyst

I'm looking for a solution to the following problem.

I want to find the shortest route for a truck, picking up garbage from households. I know the amount of garbage each household is producing and I do know how much garbage the truck can hold. The scenario is of course that the truck drives of to pick up garbage until its full, or to the point where it is almost full, but the next household is providing so much garbage that the truck would be overloaded. Then the truck should come back.

I do have ArcGIS and the Network Analyst extension at hand and was wondering if this is possible to achieve with these tools. I don't mind if there is some scripting required, that's not the problem.

Has one of you done something similar and could give me a hint on how to do it?

Comment: First, you'll have to find out the distances. But at the end this is a special case of the optimization problem called 'vehicle routing problem' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem

Comment: Danke Karussell!
So, I guess I first have to define a catchment for the facility, which is easy enough, and then do a clustering, taking the capacity of the truck into account. The latter one will be more difficult. Finally, the third step will be the actual routing depending on the cluster. Thanks for the link! Hope I can implement that soon into my routines.

Cheers, Thomas

Answer (score 1):

We did something very similar with FleetEngine (http://www.routeware.dk), but realized the amount of garbage couldn't be estimated precisely enough, so the trucks was emptied either way too early or late. The solution was to calculate it as a one long travelling salesman route and then simply ask the drivers to empty the truck when it was full. Wherever that is on the route. Depending upon distances between depot and households, truck capacity etc, the conclusion on this may be different for you.

Comment: Hi Uffe,

it's a different story with me. The garbage thing was just an example. In my case there is not much change in the monthly values of the goods to be picked up. I had a look at FleetEngine... awesome prices they have. That might be worth to spend for a company in the pick-up/delivery business, but I'm working on a scientific question in a totally non-commercial environment. Thanks anyway, it's always good to know what solutions are out there.

Cheers,
Thomas